# Feeding options into zathura with command substitution

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that I want to use to pass options into the pdf reader zathura. It outputs something like:

```
filename.pdf -P 5 -f "some search phrase"
```

The -P option gives a page number to open the pdf at and -f gives a searchterm to be highlighted. If I simply run

```
zathura filename.pdf -P 5 -f "some search phrase"
```

this works perfectly fine. It opens `filename.pdf` on page 5 and highlights the string `some search phrase`. However if I invoke the script that gives me these options via a subshell like this:

```
zathura $(myscript)
```

It seems to interpret `search` and `phrase"` as separate files. So three zathura windows open, one with the pdf opened on the correct page, but the search string being `"some` instead of `some search phrase` and then two more windows where the file can understandably not be found. It tries to open `search` and `phrase"` as files here. If I modify the script so that there are no double quotes around the argument of `-f` and search for a string that does not have spaces, it works as expected. However, I need to be able to search for phrases that have spaces in them.

I have tried all sort of things to solve this, but I am at the end of my tether at this point. The result of the command substitution is certainly correct and the behaviour can be replicated if I simply do:

```
zathura $(echo "filename.pdf -P 5 -f \"some search phrase\"")
```

List of things I tried:

- I escaped the double quotes with backslashes
- I exchanged the double quotes with single quotes, precisely the same problem persists
- I tried it in zsh instead of bash
- I escaped the spaces with backslashes
- I put double quotes around the command substitution, which obviously results in all options being interpreted as files
- I put the options before the filename
- I changed the order of the options around
- Combined several of the aforementioned

I have tried to read up on it online, but to no avail. If someone could help me with this and explain what is going on I would most appreciate it.

Comment: This: `filename.pdf -P 5 -f "some search phrase"`

Comment: You have to use an array: `options=( filename.pdf -P 5 -f "some search phrase" ); zathura "${options[@]}"`

Comment: The diff succeeds without a result

Comment: I cannot get the array solution to work either, is it supposed to have one array element for each option optarg pair?

Comment: no, one element per argument; are you using bash?

Comment: Ah, turns out in works in bash, I tried in zsh first and got `bad set of key/value pairs for associative array` Thank you!

Comment: The underlying problem is discussed in detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).